# How to Display the Particular field in edittext by id in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

how to Display the particular field details in editext by giving id here i write code in database handler but i dont know what to do in MainActivity

i have fields when i gave id and click show button the details in database for that particular id want to be load in edittext 
My database Handler class

Comment: Which error do you get? We need more info.

Comment: WILD GUESS: You forgot to move the cursor to the first record.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uxegK.jpg

Comment: First You need to pass id in getData() method.

Comment: i pass id in getdata(int id) after that also i got error

Comment: what you get when you try myDB.getData(1);

Comment: i have fields when i gave id and click show button the details in database for that particular id want to be load in edittext

Comment: @Sree it accepted but what we do next,i have 3 fields name fname and marks when i gave id and click the show button the datas for particular id want to be display in edittext how can we do

Comment: @karthickYadav look my answer hope it will help you

Comment: ya but the matter is when i pass the ID in getdata it shows error thats the matter

Comment: can you able to post the error?? are you sure you are passing a int value

Comment: when i pass getData(1) i didnot get any error but when i pass my Column id ex[getdata(int id)] i got error

Comment: what, can you able to post what you post like my Column id ex[getdata(int id)]

Comment: @karthickYadav check my answer.

Comment: @Sree check my updated code plz

Comment: What output exactly you want?

Comment: KishuDroid  thx i got @arun ans is crt and tht wht i need thx arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

set editText as number only

android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"

```
public void show()
{
   bshow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       if(uid.getText().toString().equals(""))
             return;
       int id = Integer.parseInt(uid.getText().toString());
       Cursor res=myDB.getData(id);//i got an error Here and i dont know what to do
       String NAME = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
       String SURNAME = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("SURNAME"));
       String MARKS = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("MARKS"));           

       editname.setText(NAME);
       editsurname.setText(SURNAME);
       editmark.setText(MARKS);
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: if show button click get the particular ids from sqllite and show the result in edittext i.e name, marks, surname ... correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor getData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from student_details where id="+id+"", null );

        if(res != null && res.moveToFirst()) {
            return res;
        }
        return res;

    }
```

In your activity initialize your Db class.
Now you can get value like below code ; -

```
Cursor mCur = myDb.getData(some integer value);
```

Now you can fetch value from cursor  by ;-

```
mCur .getString(mCur .getColumnIndex("column name");
```

Comment: Cursor mCur = myDb.getData(some integer value); what this interger value says??

Comment: this is the id value,suppose you want to fetch first row then you should pass 1 as integer.

Comment: See this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm
it will guide you regarding sqlite.

Comment: thanks but i want to fetch all datas in database by using ID and the particular datas want to be display in edittext field

Comment: what is ID in your terms?

Comment: ID is an autoincrement in dabase

Comment: Id is an autoincreent ..private static final String DATABASE_NAME="students.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="student_details";
    private static final String COL_1="ID";
    private static final String COL_2="NAME";
    private static final String COL_3="FNAME";
    private static final String COL_4="MARKS";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

Comment: But dear by passing id you can only get one row at a time and fetch each column using mCur .getString(mCur .getColumnIndex("column name");

Comment: thanks but my column name i declared only in Database class not in MainActivity

Comment: but here you can pass your column name as string

Comment: where that is my question bro

Comment: See i am declaring my column as 

public static final String _COLUMN_ID = "id";

and now if you pass mCur .getString(mCur .getColumnIndex("id");